# Suppose $\int_0^1 f(x)x^kdx = 0$ for any nonnegative integer $k$. Show $f\equiv 0$ on $[0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

The problem is in the title with the added assumption that $f$ is continuous. My proof is that $p_n\to f$ uniformly for some sequence of polynomials $p_n$ by the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem. So,
$$\int_0^1f(x)^2dx = \int_0^1f(x)(f(x)-p_n(x))dx$$
$$\leq\max |f|\int_0^1|f(x)-p_n(x)|dx\to 0$$
by uniform convergence of the $p_n$. Then $\int_0^1 f(x)^2dx = 0$ and $f$ continuous imply $f\equiv 0$. Does this seem correct to everyone?

Comment: How did you get that first equality?

Comment: By the assumption that $\int_0^1 f(x)x^kdx = 0$.

Comment: You have to be a little more explicit but you have the right idea.

Comment: More explicit? How so?

Comment: Since you're using one of the key assumptions at that step, it's good to make it explicit. You could say that the assumption implies $\int_0^1 f(x)p(x)dx=0$ for all polynomials $p(x)$, and so $\int_0^1 f(x)^2dx = \int_0^1 f(x)^2dx - \int_0^1 f(x)p_n(x)dx = \int_0^1 f(x)(f(x)-p_n(x))dx$. Or just $\int_0^1 f(x)^2dx = \int_0^1 f(x)(f(x)-p_n(x))dx$, depending on who you're writing for.

Comment: Also, Weierstrass' theorem is about convergence in $L^\infty$ and here you're talking about $L^1$ convergence. You should explain that slightly. Also see: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~thomases/201A_F10_hw5_sol.pdf

Answer (score 2):

This looks right.  For the record, this was problem B7 [sic] in the 1958 Putnam exam (actually the question asked about functions on an arbitrary fixed interval $[a,b]$, but that's equivalent to $[0,1]$ by linear change of variable), and the published solution uses Weierstrass Approximation as you do.

Comment: Thanks! It was on my comp exam this morning... ugh, Putnam.

Comment: Well the Putnam was a different beast 50+ years ago.

Comment: Also, if the published solution was not the same as mine (showing $\int f^2 = 0$), would you mind posting it?

Comment: It's basically the same as yours; see the first book of Putnam problems and solutions.